How do I properly authenticate with OAuth using google-auth-oauthlib and Django?
I am building a Django project that works with video and needs to upload to Youtube. For this, I need oauth credentials. I am unable to authenticate with Oauth even though my redirect URI is correct and I am parsing the request for the code and passing it to the flow.
I am using google-auth-oauthlib and oauth to authenticate. Here is what the error looks like:
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/home/team/lotteh/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner    response = get_response(request)               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  File "/home/team/lotteh/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response    response = wrapped_callback(request,
*callback_args, **callback_kwargs)               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  File "/home/team/lotteh/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/views.py", line 89, in sentry_wrapped_callback    return callback(request, *args,
**kwargs)           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  File "/home/team/lotteh/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 65, in _view_wrapper    return view_func(request, *args,
**kwargs)           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  File "/home/team/lotteh/users/views.py", line 47, in google_auth_callback   email, token, refresh = parse_callback_url(request, code)              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  File "/home/team/lotteh/users/oauth.py", line 66, in parse_callback_url    flow.fetch_token(code=token_url)  File "/home/team/lotteh/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py", line 285, in fetch_token    return self.oauth2session.fetch_token(self.client_config["token_uri"],
**kwargs)           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/home/team/lotteh/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_session.py", line 406, in fetch_token    self._client.parse_request_body_response(r.text, scope=self.scope)  File "/home/team/lotteh/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/clients/base.py", line 415, in parse_request_body_response    self.token = parse_token_response(body, scope=scope)                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  File "/home/team/lotteh/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py", line 425, in parse_token_response    validate_token_parameters(params) File "/home/team/lotteh/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py", line 432, in validate_token_parameters    raise_from_error(params.get('error'), params)  File "/home/team/lotteh/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/errors.py", line 405, in raise_from_error    raise cls(**kwargs)oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.InvalidGrantError: (invalid_grant) Bad Request

And the views:
def google_auth(request):
    from django.shortcuts import redirect
    from users.oauth import get_auth_url
    import uuid
    url, state = get_auth_url(request, request.user.email if request.user.is_authenticated else None)
    print(state)
    request.session['state'] = state
    return redirect(url)

#@login_required
#@user_passes_test(is_superuser_or_vendor)

@csrf_exempt
def google_auth_callback(request):
    from users.oauth import parse_callback_url
    from security.middleware import get_qs
    from django.shortcuts import redirect
    from django.urls import reverse
    from django.conf import settings
    url = settings.BASE_URL + request.path + request.GET.urlencode()
    code = request.GET['code']
    email, token, refresh = parse_callback_url(request, code)
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    user = User.objects.filter(email=email).order_by('-last_seen').last()
    if not user:
        from users.username_generator import generate_username as get_random_username
        user = User.objects.create_user(email=e, username=get_random_username(), password=get_random_string(length=8))
        from django.contrib import messages
        messages.success(request, 'You are now subscribed, check your email for a confirmation. When you get the chance, fill out the form below to make an account.')
    user.profile.token = token
    user.profile.refresh_token = refresh
    user.profile.save()
    from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login
    auth_login(request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
    from django.contrib import messages
    messages.success(request, 'Successfully linked Google account')
    return redirect(reverse('/'))

And the helper functions seen above (users/oauth.py)
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse
import os

flows = {}

def get_auth_url(request, email):
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(str(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'client_secret.json')),
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    ])
    flow.redirect_uri = settings.BASE_URL + reverse('users:oauth')
    authorization_url, state = None, None
    if email:
        authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
            access_type='offline',
            include_granted_scopes='true',
            state=request.session.get('state'),
            login_hint=email,
            prompt='consent')
    else:
        authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
            access_type='offline',
            include_granted_scopes='true',
            state=request.session.get('state'),
            prompt='consent')
    global flows
    flows[state] = flow
    return authorization_url, state

def get_user_info(credentials):
  """Send a request to the UserInfo API to retrieve the user's information.

  Args:
    credentials: oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials instance to authorize the
                 request.
  Returns:
    User information as a dict.
  """
  user_info_service = build(
      serviceName='oauth2', version='v2',
      http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))
  user_info = None
  try:
    user_info = user_info_service.userinfo().get().execute()
  except (errors.HttpError, e):
    logging.error('An error occurred: %s', e)
  if user_info and user_info.get('id'):
    return user_info
  else:
    raise Exception()

def parse_callback_url(request, token_url):
    global flows
    flow = flows[request.GET.get('state')]
    flow.fetch_token(code=token_url)
    credentials = flow.credentials
    return get_user_info(credentials)['email'], credentials.token, credentials.refresh_token

This is the line that fails, at the end:
    flow.fetch_token(code=token_url)
Everything else seems to work properly. Please let me know if you know any way to fix this. I haven't been able to get OAuth to work with a package, although I tried Django allauth. I am using Django 5, the latest version, on Ubuntu 24 with an Apache server. The web server is working and redirects to the callback URL, but the callback is broken. Please help, any help and ideas is appreciated.
